# xpath expression for node value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need an xpath expression that will split an xml document based on a condition whereby I get one document for each unique  (like in the example below).

The xml sample below should result in 2 documents (id 100 and 200).  I don't want to hardcode values...

Any ideas how I can do this with xpath expression?

(I know I can get 4 documents with expression /data/employee)

Example:

```
<data>
    <employee>
        <id>100</id>
        <tag>A</tag>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>100</id>
        <tag>B</tag>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>200</id>
        <tag>A</tag>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>200</id>
        <tag>B</tag>
    </employee>
</data>
```

Example Output:

Document #1

```
<data>
    <employee>
        <id>100</id>
        <tag>A</tag>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>100</id>
        <tag>B</tag>
    </employee>
</data>
```

Document #2

```
<data>
    <employee>
        <id>200</id>
        <tag>A</tag>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>200</id>
        <tag>B</tag>
    </employee>
</data>
```

Comment: XPath is a query language, it does not split/transform/create documents. Are you looking for XSLT?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 this is a standard grouping use case:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="employee" group-by="id">
  <xsl:result-document href="{position()}.xml">
    <data>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </data>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath is a query language, not a document transformation. Therefore, the task can not be done with XPath only. Your question also does not tell anything about the environment it is running in, so it is not possible to give a thorough answer.

That being said, this approach might be what you need:

- Query for `/data/employee/id` and add the node values to a set (e.g. a bag of distinct values).
- Loop over the distinct values, and build a query like this to get the matching nodes for each employee: `/data/employee[id=ID]` (where you substitute `ID` with the distinct value you are currently iterating on).
- You could use these results to build your derived documents, but how this is done depends on the environment.